# How make Wordpress overrides URL in nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have the current syntax in my `nginx` server block in `/sites-available/`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

Actually i have a WordPress installation in my root folder. And I have some folders mixed in the root folder too. So looks like these:

https://mywebsite.com/mycustomfolder/foo/bar/ <- WordPress URL

https://mywebsite.com/mycustomfolder/ <- Folder with simple HTML files

I need to access both of the cases. But the `nginx` is forcing somehow to just access `/mycustomfolder/` who have no files and I get a `403 Forbidden` or I access the files normally if have them.

So, what I desire is, if there is no files or folder, just keep `WordPress` show a `404 page` or a custom created. And if there is files or folder, show them as HTML/PHP normally.

Comment: Where is the directory `mycustomfolder` located? What is the value of your `root` directive?

Comment: Hi Richard, so is like this: `/var/www/mywebsite.com/html/mycustomfolder/` and the WordPress is in root folder as `/var/www/mywebsite.com/html/index.php`

Comment: And the `root` directive is: `server { root /var/www/mywebsite.com/html; index index.php index.html index.htm;`